how to detect php curl query
I'm currently facing an issue with a PHP request made using cURL. When I send a request to this URL: https://lmt.fn.sportradar.com/common/fr/Etc:UTC/gismo/match_info/43067423 with cURL, I receive a 403 (Forbidden) response, whereas when I use Postman to send the same request, I receive a 200 (OK) response. I've double-checked that the request parameters are the same in both cases, but I can't understand why I'm getting different responses.
Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this difference in behavior between cURL and Postman? Are there significant differences in how these two tools send requests that could explain this problem?
Here are the headers via PHP cURL:
Remote-Ip: [ip]
Accept: */*
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.2
X-Ovhrequest-Id: [id]
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Forwarded-For: [ip]
X-Predictor: 1
Host: [myhost.com]

And here are the headers via Postman:
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.2
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: c61cd895-cb03-458b-8309-849e91f6b6d6
Host: localhost:8888
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive

Her php Query
// custom headers
$headers = [
    'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.2',
    'Accept: */*',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'X-Ovhrequest-Id:',
    'X-Forwarded-Proto:',
    'X-Forwarded-For:',
    'X-Predictor:'
];


// init cURL
$curl = curl_init();

// curl config
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // URL à requêter
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Retourner la réponse dans une variable
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Suivre les redirections
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); // Temps d'attente maximal de connexion
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); // Temps d'attente maximal de la requête
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); // En-têtes personnalisés
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // Ne pas inclure les en-têtes de la réponse dans la sortie


// run query
$response = curl_exec($curl);

For Postman : just query get classic

"I'm currently facing an issue with a PHP request made using cURL" ... Can you show your code that makes the request? Your code in PHP?

Show the curl/php code. Show the postman request. You can [edit] your post btw

Sorry for that ^^, i will edit

Please only use English in your question.

This site is performing a user agent check and explicitly denying unrecognized agents. This is likely to deter what you're trying to do. But it's a really ineffective way to control access, and trivially worked around. Just have curl emulate a browser by specifying the user agent string of (for example) Chrome:
curl -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' 'https://lmt.fn.sportradar.com/common/fr/Etc:UTC/gismo/match_info/43067423'

Or via PHP:
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36');


it's seems to be that, but why I place header User-Agent with CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER it's not work ?
